# Which property or method should i use to bind the ToolTip property to an ImageField Class?

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding, gridview, imagefield

In an image control that is bound within a GridView column i can set the Alt text property by using the `DataAlternateTextField` property.

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Flag" 
     DataImageUrlFormatString="~/images/f/{0}.png"
     DataAlternateTextField="Description"  >
</asp:ImageField>
```

which results in somathing like...

```
<img src="1.png" alt="Alt text"/>
```

Which property or method should i use to bind the ToolTip property?

```
<img src="1.png" alt="Alt text"  ToolTip="Title text" />
```

I would like the users of the website, on mouse hovering of the image, to be able to read the title property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use binding expression to set the title of the ImageField. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx

Comment: Which means that i have to convert the image to an ItemTemplate first?

Comment: Yes if it is part of GridView or other control as I suppose :)

Answer (score 2):

To all newbies out there just like me, here what i did

```
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test" SortExpression="">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Flag", "~/images/f/{0}.png") %>' 
                    AlternateText='<%# Bind("Description") %>' 
                    ToolTip='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks Veronica

Answer (score 0):

I am playing with this issue now according to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagefield.dataalternatetextfield%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the alternate text property of an ImageField should translate into a tooltip as well. At least that's what it says on the msdn page i just linked.